# Simple webclient response in textbox (or listbox)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

can not make it work, whatever I tried so far.

I want to make a Remote Camera Commander application (WPF/C#) in Visual Studio 2015 that consists of a number buttons that, when clicked, do a web request to a network camera. I am not a programmer, so I am starting from scratch.

Have searched the internet for many days now and tested many examples, but when inserting a piece of example code into my code, always new issues arise.

I have made an example that hopefully explains my issues:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="RCC_1v1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RCC_1v1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="GetCameraType_Button" Click="GetType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" Height="86"/>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="response" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" Margin="246,112,0,0" TextChanged="response_TextChanged">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text ="How to get the response from webclient into this textbox, instead of in the messagebox??"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace RCC_1v1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private void GetType(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("stackO", "12345");
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://eremote-cam1.eu.ngrok.io/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=root.Brand"));
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        }

        private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
        }

        private void response_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You can run it yourself with the temp. the account that is embedded. Not sure if I should use TextBox or any other object like listview or.

The expected responses are text-string and single numbers.

[image]

Any tip, direction or help is appreciated.

Just followed some of your suggestions, code is now:

```
enter code hereusing System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;

namespace RCC_1v2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private void GetType(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("stackO", "54321");
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://eremote-cam1.eu.ngrok.io/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=root.Brand.ProdFullName"));
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }


    private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            String run_text = e.Result.ToString();
            Run1.Text = run_text.Substring(24, 13);

        }));
    }

   }
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTAOd.png)

Comment: `response.Text = e.Result`?

Comment: Subscribe event first (wc.DownloadStringCompleted +=...) then start download (wc.DownloadStringAsync(...))

Comment: Why a RichTextBox? Do you want to edit the result text? To get it right from the beginning, take a look at [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) and MVVM. Create a `ResultText` property in a view model class (that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface), bind the Text property of  TextBlock to the view model property. Set the view model property in the DownloadStringCompleted handler.

Answer (score 1):

Give the name "Run1" to the Run contained in your XAML using x:Name attribute.

Replace your code:
MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
with this one:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            this.Run1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
        }));
```

The event DownloadStringCompleted runs in a background thread, so if you want to update the UI you must use the Dispatcher property of the Window class.

Comment: Thanks, stil working on all of your suggestions. ie. Textbox instead of RichTextBox and the alternative Dispatcher code. I have response now in RichTextBox, although with errors. Will give an update with final code later on.

Comment: Thanks Igor, your code was very helpful. Also thanks to the other posters. As I am not allowed yet (reputation or not understand how etc) I  can not add any comments on the main thread, therefore  I am not able to show you further details about the solution I found. Just added to the main post with edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found out about the idea of posting an answer. With help of the posters I created the next example/solution:

```
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Windows;

 namespace RCC_1v2
 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private void GetType(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://eremote-cam1.eu.ngrok.io/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=root.Brand.ProdFullName"));
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }


    private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            String run_text = e.Result.ToString();
            Run1.Text = run_text.Substring(24, 13);

        }));
    }

}
}
```

Mainwindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="RCC_1v2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RCC_1v2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="GetCameraType_Button" Click="GetType"     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="86"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="Run1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" Margin="206,113,0,0" >
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see I now have the response in the texbox (and not a RichTextBox)

nb. I was not allowed to post a picture :-(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVlb9.png)

Thanks!